# I cant deploy the middleman project

Tags: ruby, deployment, rubygems, middleman

[image]

this is the gem file

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'middleman', '~> 4.2'
gem 'middleman-autoprefixer', '~> 2.7'
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mswin, :mingw, :jruby, :x64_mingw]
gem 'wdm', '~> 0.1', platforms: [:mswin, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
gem "middleman-blog", "~> 4.0"
# Other gems
gem 'middleman-deploy', '~> 2.0.0.pre.alpha'
gem 'middleman-syntax', '~> 3.0'
gem 'redcarpet', '~> 3.4'
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.8', '>= 1.8.2'
gem 'builder', '~> 3.2', '>= 3.2.3'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.beta2.1'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.7.0'
gem 'rails-assets-jquery', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'
gem 'rails-assets-popper.js', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'
gem 'rails-assets-modernizr', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'
```

How can I fix that! I cant deploy this What is the problem over here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lol :smile: You have to **build** before

```
    middleman build
```

```
    middleman deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as an additional note (since I don't have enough reputation to comment) — you can configure middleman-deploy to automatically build the site each time you deploy by adding `deploy.build_before = true` in your `config.rb`, like this:

```rb
activate :deploy do |deploy|
  deploy.deploy_method = :git
  deploy.remote = 'https://github.com/your-username/your-repository.git'
  deploy.branch = 'main' # (or whatever your branch is; presumably you've already got this set up)
  deploy.build_before = true
end
```